# why append() function of python not working with list of list?

Tags: python, list, append, nested-lists

```
t = [ [1,22] , [1,44] ]# nested list
list1 = t.append( [0,0] )
print list1
```

I want the result to be [ [1,22] , [1,44] , [0,0] ]. But the output is always "None" . What should I  do?

Answer (score 1):

The `append()` method modifies the list in place and the return value is None. Just view `t` and you will see the appended item.

```
t = [ [1,22] , [1,44] ]# nested list
t.append( [0,0] )
print t
```